# Error en modulos

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero hacer un módulo pero no funciona y no se porque. Tengo en la misma carpeta dos archivos .py3: funcion_mates y llamar_funcion_mates.
En funcion_mates tengo funciones que realizan operaciones y funciona.
En llamar_funcion_mates tengo:

```
import funcion_mates 
funcion_mates.sumar(3,3)
```

Y me da este error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'funcion_mates'

Tengo que configurar el PATH de Python o algo así?

Comment: Quita el `3` de la extensión `funcion_mates.py` y no `funcion_mates.py3` o Python no va a reconocer el archivo. Si ambos están en el mismo directorio no tienes que hacer nada más.

Comment: Ahora si funciona, gracias! Pero el archivo funcion_mates ya no es la version 3 de Python. ¿Porque no funciona con la 3 versión?

Comment: La extensión .py3 nunca a estado soportada, la extensión para módulos en Python 3 siempre ha sido .py igual que para Python 2, aunque hay quien use py3 esta no es reconocida por el intérprete y su uso es minoritario. Ten en cuenta que las extensiones en Linux no significan absolutamente nada, el intérprete a usar se especifica vía shebang no por extensión.

Comment: Gracias por aclararmelo